# CakePHP unit tests generating errors on my system

Tags: php, unit-testing, internationalization, cakephp-3.2

I've come across a couple of issues in CakePHP that I want to submit fixes for, but I want to make sure that any changes I make pass the unit tests. Problem is that the unit tests don't quite work for me with out-of-the-box code! I'm assured that the unit tests themselves are fine and pass just fine for others, so it's presumably something in my environment causing the problem.

I'm running CakePHP version 3.2.5 on PHP version 5.6.19. My PHP build configuration (included because I had to rebuild it a couple of times to get it to run this much of the tests, so it's theoretically possible that this is the problem):

`'./configure'  '--enable-fileinfo' '--enable-phar' '--disable-maintainer-zts' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--enable-libxml' '--enable-mbstring' '--enable-pdo=shared' '--enable-sockets' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--with-curl' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-gd' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-kerberos' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-mssql=/usr' '--with-mysql=/usr' '--with-mysqli=/usr/bin/mysql_config' '--with-pcre-regex' '--with-pdo-mysql=shared' '--without-sqlite' '--with-sqlite3=shared' '--with-pdo-sqlite=shared,/usr' '--with-pic' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--enable-intl'`

There may also be php.ini settings that affect some of this?

#### Commands used to set up CakePHP for the tests

```
$ git clone git@github.com:cakephp/cakephp.git
$ cd cakephp
```

#### First try

```
$ make test
[bunch of stuff here where it installs all the dependencies]
vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 5.2.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.............................................................   61 / 6777 (  0%)
[etc.]
............................................................. 1159 / 6777 ( 17%)
........FF......PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on null in /home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/DateTest.php on line 170

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on null in /home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/DateTest.php on line 170
make: *** [test] Error 255
```

This one is because it's trying to parse "13 10, 2015" using the fr_FR locale, but it seems that's not valid. I fixed it by changing the string to "13/10/2015" on lines 169 and 185. (I also added `assertNotNull` calls.)

#### Second try

```
$ make test
[etc.]
............................................................. 4209 / 6777 ( 62%)
.......................FF.......................PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function format() on null in /home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/TimeTypeTest.php on line 184

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on null in /home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/TimeTypeTest.php on line 184
make: *** [test] Error 255
```

I didn't fully track this one down, just got it to fail and allow the tests to proceed by adding `$this->assertNotNull($result);`.

#### Third try

```
$ make test
[etc.]
There were 5 errors:

1) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\IcuFormatterTest::testNativePluralSelection
Aura\Intl\Exception\CannotInstantiateFormatter: msgfmt_create: message formatter creation failed: U_ILLEGAL_CHARACTER

/home/cake/cakephp/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php:97
/home/cake/cakephp/src/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatter.php:51
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/Formatter/IcuFormatterTest.php:81

2) Cake\Test\TestCase\ORM\QueryTest::testCountWithSubselect
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range

/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/BufferedStatement.php:74
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/SqliteStatement.php:41
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:270
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Query.php:188
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:793
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:739
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/ORM/QueryTest.php:1543
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

3) Cake\Test\TestCase\ORM\QueryTest::testCountWithExpressions
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range

/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/BufferedStatement.php:74
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/SqliteStatement.php:41
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:270
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Query.php:188
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:793
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:739
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/ORM/QueryTest.php:1564
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

4) Cake\Test\TestCase\ORM\QueryTest::testCountWithSubselect
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range

/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/BufferedStatement.php:74
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/SqliteStatement.php:41
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:270
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Query.php:188
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:793
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:739
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/ORM/QueryTest.php:1543
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

5) Cake\Test\TestCase\ORM\QueryTest::testCountWithExpressions
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 25 bind or column index out of range

/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/StatementDecorator.php:171
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/BufferedStatement.php:74
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Statement/SqliteStatement.php:41
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Connection.php:270
/home/cake/cakephp/src/Database/Query.php:188
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:793
/home/cake/cakephp/src/ORM/Query.php:739
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/ORM/QueryTest.php:1564
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

--

There were 26 failures:

1) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\DateTest::testI18nFormat with data set "mutable" ('Cake\I18n\Date')
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'jeudi 14 janvier 2010 00:00:00 UTC'
+'jeudi 14 janvier 2010 00:00:00 UTC+00:00'

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/DateTest.php:112

2) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\DateTest::testI18nFormat with data set "immutable" ('Cake\I18n\FrozenDate')
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'jeudi 14 janvier 2010 00:00:00 UTC'
+'jeudi 14 janvier 2010 00:00:00 UTC+00:00'

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/DateTest.php:112

3) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\NumberTest::testCurrency
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'â‚¹Â 10,01,00,100.00'
+'RsÂ 10,01,00,100.00'

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/NumberTest.php:206

4) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\NumberTest::testConfig
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'â‚¹Â 15,000.00'
+'RsÂ 15,000.00'

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/NumberTest.php:550

5) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\NumberTest::testOrdinal
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'1st'
+'1Ë¢áµ—'

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/NumberTest.php:569

6) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testI18nFormat with data set "mutable" ('Cake\I18n\Time')
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-jueves 14 de enero de 2010 13:59:28 GMT
+jueves 14 de enero de 2010 13:59:28 GMT+00:00

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:858
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:439

7) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testI18nFormat with data set "immutable" ('Cake\I18n\FrozenTime')
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-jueves 14 de enero de 2010 13:59:28 GMT
+jueves 14 de enero de 2010 13:59:28 GMT+00:00

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:858
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:439

8) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testI18nFormatWithOffsetTimezone with data set "mutable" ('Cake\I18n\Time')
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-Wednesday January 1 2014 12:00:00 AM GMT
+Wednesday January 1 2014 12:00:00 AM GMT+00:00

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:858
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:496

9) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testI18nFormatWithOffsetTimezone with data set "immutable" ('Cake\I18n\FrozenTime')
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-Wednesday January 1 2014 12:00:00 AM GMT
+Wednesday January 1 2014 12:00:00 AM GMT+00:00

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:858
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:496

10) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testToString with data set "mutable" ('Cake\I18n\Time')
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-dimanche 20 avril 2014 22:10:00 UTC
+dimanche 20 avril 2014 22:10:00 UTC+00:00

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:858
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:567

11) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testToString with data set "immutable" ('Cake\I18n\FrozenTime')
Failed asserting that two strings are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-dimanche 20 avril 2014 22:10:00 UTC
+dimanche 20 avril 2014 22:10:00 UTC+00:00

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:858
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:567

12) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testParseDateTime with data set "mutable" ('Cake\I18n\Time')
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:746

13) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testParseDateTime with data set "immutable" ('Cake\I18n\FrozenTime')
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:746

14) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testParseDate with data set "mutable" ('Cake\I18n\Time')
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:780

15) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testParseDate with data set "immutable" ('Cake\I18n\FrozenTime')
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:780

16) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testParseTime with data set "mutable" ('Cake\I18n\Time')
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:800

17) Cake\Test\TestCase\I18n\TimeTest::testParseTime with data set "immutable" ('Cake\I18n\FrozenTime')
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/I18n/TimeTest.php:800

18) Cake\Test\TestCase\Network\ResponseTest::testOutputCompressed
Failed asserting that true is false.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Network/ResponseTest.php:532

19) Cake\Test\TestCase\Validation\ValidationTest::testLocalizedTime
Failed asserting that false is true.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Validation/ValidationTest.php:1570

20) Cake\Test\TestCase\View\Helper\TimeHelperTest::testFormat
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'Thursday January 14 2010 1:59:28 PM GMT'
+'Thursday January 14 2010 1:59:28 PM GMT+00:00'

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/View/Helper/TimeHelperTest.php:499
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/View/Helper/TimeHelperTest.php:441

21) Cake\Test\TestCase\Database\Type\DateTimeTypeTest::testLocaleParserDisable
null does not match expected type "object".

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/DateTimeTypeTest.php:227
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

22) Cake\Test\TestCase\Database\Type\DateTimeTypeTest::testMarshalWithLocaleParsing
null does not match expected type "object".

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/DateTimeTypeTest.php:244
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

23) Cake\Test\TestCase\Database\Type\TimeTypeTest::testMarshalWithLocaleParsing
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/TimeTypeTest.php:184
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

24) Cake\Test\TestCase\Database\Type\DateTimeTypeTest::testLocaleParserDisable
null does not match expected type "object".

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/DateTimeTypeTest.php:227
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

25) Cake\Test\TestCase\Database\Type\DateTimeTypeTest::testMarshalWithLocaleParsing
null does not match expected type "object".

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/DateTimeTypeTest.php:244
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

26) Cake\Test\TestCase\Database\Type\TimeTypeTest::testMarshalWithLocaleParsing
Failed asserting that null is not null.

/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/Database/Type/TimeTypeTest.php:184
/home/cake/cakephp/tests/TestCase/DatabaseSuite.php:68

FAILURES!
Tests: 6777, Assertions: 20613, Errors: 5, Failures: 26, Skipped: 144.
make: *** [test] Error 2
```

The majority of these issues appear to be i18n related. Would love to be able to get this resolved so that I can make PRs with confidence!

Comment: Problems with differen ICU versions are pretty common. You'll most probably get better help on IRC, where devs hang out that have been dealing with this a lot already.

Comment: Another fail for CentOS and their extremely conservative views on updating system libraries. Updating ICU from the source and re-rebuilding PHP has eliminated all but a handful of errors, which are SQLite-related and could presumably be eliminated by updating that too.